# True or false? About unitary operation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite inner product space. Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation. Suppose that $v_1,...,v_n$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$ such that $(Tv_i,Tv_i)=1$ for every $1\leq i\leq n$. Then $T$ is unitary operation.

Is that statement true?

Comment: I believe this is true. Being unitary is equivalent $(Tx,Ty)=(x,y)$ for all $x$ and $y$ as well as $T$ being surjective. I think your condition on orthonormal bases should provide both of these

Comment: This is false like that as observed by Adam Saltz. If you add $(Tv_i,Tv_j)=0$ for $i\neq j$, then it is true. As it becomes equivalent to $(Tv_i)$ being an orthonormal set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unitary operators are invertible and therefore surjective.  There are non-surjective maps which satisfy the condition above, so not all operators satisfying that condition are unitary.

Consider the map $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $(x,y) \to (x+y,0)$.  Taking the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$, we find that $\langle T(1,0), T(1,0) \rangle = 1$ and $\langle T(0,1), T(0,1) \rangle = 1$.  Therefore $T$ satisfies the above condition, but it is not invertible and therefore not unitary.